# switchport block multicast vs storm-control multicast

Tags: cisco, switch, multicast

I'm not sure what is the difference in behaviour between `switchport block multicast` and `storm-control multicast` and I don't think cisco elaborates the difference very well in their documentation, other than the fact storm-control grants you levels of control, but for this case, suppose the storm-control only lets you pick up 0 or 100. How is it any different from switchport block, for instance?

Update: I accidentally wrote "switchport block unicast" when I intended to write "switchport block multicast".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well the first difference would be that `switchport block unicast` blocks unknown unicast and `storm-control multicast` blocks multicast packets.

The difference between `switchport block XXXcast` and `storm-control XXXcast` is exactly what you want to exclude in your question. You can pick any percent value for `storm-control`. It will block traffic of the specified type which exceeds this percentage of bandwidth on the port. `switchport block` is a simple yes/no. It blocks everything when activated.

**Update:**

As ytti mentioned, on some low-end boxes when `storm-control multicast` is exceeded all traffic will get filtered. In that case `storm-control multicast` is dangerous and useless.

Also on high-bandwidth interfaces (1/10GE) please remember that even a small percentage of the bandwidth can kill a box that punts the packets to the CPU. If possible use CoPP to protect the control plane. Also always use pps instead of bps for CoPP if possible.

Comment: Some low-end switches, like 3550 when 'storm-control multicast' is exceeded all traffic is filtered, not just multicast, which makes it highly unusable. Also when I see people configuring storm-control broadcast I regularly see them setting ridiculously large values, WS-X6704-10GE minimum possible value 0.34% is higher than you want (box will die for 0.34% @ 10GE).

Comment: hmm 34MBit/s are probably enough, yes. CoPP could perhaps help in that case.

Comment: That reminds me, when platform allows doing storm-control or CoPP in pps, always use pps instead of bps.

Comment: Thanks, I accidentally mistyped my question, but your answer was clever enough to cover what I wanted to know. I have 2 questions, out of your explanation:
1. What is considered an "unknown *cast"
2. Why can it kill the box?

Comment: 1) There is only 'unknown unicast'. It means that the switch/router does not know on which port the destination MAC address is and so it floods the packet to all ports (except the one where he received it from).

Comment: 2) Because the CPU has to look at every packet it receives and that can take a lot of CPU time. The CPU is also needed for other stuff like keeping all the control protocols running (STP, LACP, BGP, IGPs...) it can't do that if it's overwhelmed with "useless" packets. Various features on the switch (e.g. IGMP snooping) will punt packets to the CPU. This is not a problem with unknown unicast but with multicast and perhaps broadcast traffic.